# jQuery swiperight event not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've got a drawer div that comes out from the right on click. I want it to close when it gets swiped to the right and I've tried using the jQuery swiperight event but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading a version of jQuery mobile on your page?
I think the `'swiperight'` event is from jQuery mobile.
Try adding it to your list of scripts.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

https://api.jquerymobile.com/swiperight/

Comment: What version of jQuery mobile are you using? It looks like 'pageinit' was deprecated, try to replace with 'pagecreate' if you are > 1.4.0

Comment: Oops! Make sure your jQuery version is compatible with your jQuery mobile version... Just in case. Try jQuery 1.11 or so